# How to associate an int value to a selected text value?

Tags: jquery, string, integer, jquery-autocomplete

I have a set of `(int,string)` pairs I need to display in a JQuery auto-complete box. When a user selects one of the possible string values, I want to get the corresponding int value. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: What autocomplete plugin are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I am no expert in Javascript. I wanted to use: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete, but if there is another user-friendly solution, I would consider it.

Comment: That plugin is deprecated in favor of the [jQueryUI version](http://www.jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete). Is using that one an option for you? Also, are you using local data or remote data?

Comment: I am using local data from an array of pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQueryUI [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete) works very well, however it's not designed to give a corresponding int value when something is autocompleted, so you'll have to make a few adjustments to the [select event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) and maybe store the int value in a hidden input field.

Another option is to, on the backend, lookup the int value using the selected string, which is how I'm doing it right now.

Comment: I was scared I would have to search the int value back from my array once I have the selected event, but ok, I can live with that...

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible dude

this is Jquery Code :

```
$("#txt1").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",                        
            url: "YourAddress",           
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",                                                    
            success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                return {
                    id: item.Value,
                    value: item.Text
                }
            }))
        }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#hdnId").val(ui.item.id);//Put Id in a hidden field
    }
});
```

call you ajax request and return JSON data something like this :

```
[{"Value":val1,"Text":"text1"},
{"Value":val2,"Text":"text2"}]
```

I tested it.It works great man

Good luck.Foroughi